# Showing a div and keep it show() if i clicked on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').focusin(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('#div').show();
    } else {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
      // If not empty value, show div
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $('#div').show();
      } else {
        $('#div').hide();
      }    
    });
  });
  $('#input').focusout(function() {
    $('#div').hide();

  });

});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
  <a href='website.com'>Link From AJAX<a>
</div>
<input id='input' type='text'>
```

In this jquery code, the `#div` shows when i type something inside the `#input` but if i tried to click on the `#div` it disappears and the link doesn't work,

How can i keep the `#div` shown if i clicked on `#div` or `#input` only, But anything outside will hide it as normal?

The Problem happens because of `position: absolute; bottom 20px` line in `CSS`.

Updated the code and suddenly it worked as intended after adding `if` statement after `.focusin function`, For previous error solution, remove the `position and bottom` in the `CSS`

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind an event handler inside another event handler. Every time focus enters the input, you'll duplicate the keyup handler.

Comment: @Barmar I solved the problem as i stated in the update, But i have the same problem after adding `AJAX` code, About the duplicate, I hope if you explain it, Because sometimes if i `focusedout` the `input` and returned to it, The `div` appears to have a new value or refreshed itself, Is that what you meant? If yes, I hope for a way to solve that too.

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, post it as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar it was an older version of the question which was solved, Do i put it?

Comment: I don't see how the AJAX call will prevent `$("#div").hide()` from happening when the input loses focus.

Comment: My comment about the handler inside another handler was unrelated to the problem. You need to fix that regardless of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the effect of the `focusout` handler by the use of a flag:

```js
var noHide = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').keyup(function() {
    // If not empty value, show div
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('#div').show();
    } else {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
  });
  $('#div a').hover(
    function() { noHide = true; },
    function() { noHide = false; $('#input').focus(); }
  );
  $('#input').focusout(function() {
    if(!noHide) {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
   <a href='#'>HellWorld</a>
</div>
<input id='input' type='text'>
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly for the first problem, But it worked with adding `if` statement as i explained in the update, But now a new problem occurred, I hope if you check it.

Answer (score 0):

When you blur out of the input, check if the currently active element is the DIV, and hide it if it isn't.

Also, if you're positioning an element absolutely, you need to give it a z-index so you can click on it. Otherwise, the click is sent to the normally-positioned element at that location.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('#div').show();
    } else {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    if (!$("#div").is(":focus,:active")) {
      $("#div").hide();
    }
  });
  $('#input').keyup(function() {
    // If not empty value, show div
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $('#div').show();
    } else {
      $('#div').hide();
    }
    var search = $('#input').val();
    $.post('search.php', {
      search: search
    }, function(data) {
      $('#div').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>
  <a href='www.someplace.com'>HellWorld</a>
</div>
<input id='input' type='text'>
```

Comment: Yes, Understood that now, About both subject you talked about. I've updated the question, The problem appeared to be the `position: absolute; bottom 20px;` in the `CSS`.